# something like "http://test:<a b>" is not getting displayed in text area in IE

Tags: javascript, user-interface, internet-explorer

Anything given inside a tag is not getting displayed in a particular text area in IE.

example : http://test:

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your source code so we can see how you're trying to add text to the text area.

Comment: `textarea` cannot have HTML content, only plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you wrote exactly **http://test:**  and it is not displaying the text inside the tag? On my side it is displaying in IE 11.

Sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function add_txt()
{
document.getElementById("t_area").value = "http://test:<a b>";

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="t_area">
 
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="add text" onclick="add_txt()">
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

It was recongnized as text so it can be displayed. If you try to add HTML inside textarea then it will not going to display. this is the behavior with all the browsers not just with IE.

So if you try to add a text it will surely display it.

You can try to make a test with above code. If your issue still persist then try to provide a sample code to produce the issue. I will try to make a test with it on my side.